# Deleting files on a remote machine

Tags: c#, file-io

Is it possible to connect to a remote machine and delete files from it? If not, are there any other approaches that can achieve this task?

One thought is that I could create a service that runs on each machine, implement a method that deletes local files, and then send commands to that service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can reach it through a standard unc network path, then that is the easiest way.  `\\machinename\c$\`.  You have to be an admin on the machine to reach that path.  This works with the System.IO objects (File, Directory, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

If you can't get to the network share, you could create a batch file to execute remotely.

So remove.bat

```
c:\
cd \Windows\system32\example\
rm *
```

and use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to copy the bat to the remote computer and execute it there.

```
psexec \\example-computer -f -c remove.bat
```

After psexec exits, the bat has completed running on the remote computer.

psexec uses netbios, so you should be able to initiate a netbios session to the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a machine on your LAN or VPN, you can use a UNC path, but you'll have to know each machine's username and password.  You would need to use the [WNetUseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385482(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API from C# to connect to the computer.  Once connected you can delete files using the normal method.  Just specify the full UNC path of the file `\\machine\c$\file.txt`.

If the machine is across the network and not on your LAN nor VPN, WCF sounds like what you're looking for.  You can create a service contract with an operation of delete file.   There is a great [introduction to WCF services here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx).